# How do I get a value from a specific column and row from CLI output in Python 3

Tags: arrays, string, multidimensional-array, python-3.7

I have output from a CLI application that looks something like:

```
Client ID Name       Value 1 Value 2
5         Joe last   5 1     5 2
6         Frank Last 6 1     6 2
```

Questions, of the data I may want to ask.

1. What is ID for Frank. (Returns: 6)
2. What is ID in row 1 of data. (Returns: 5)
3. Of course I could ask for any column

The values are standard CLI output and have a random count of spaces between each column.  The size of the output will never be more than a few hundred lines.  Most of the time less 10 or 20 lines.

Would be great if there was a library to convert this data into a dictionary then I could just query the correct column and row.

Answer (score 0):

Well... here is a possible answer.  I would like to do a couple of small things like get rid of the field names from the first row in the list.  Also address the fields using the column name so the calling code would be easier to read (e.g. theList['Name'][1]).  This answer pretty good for now.  I can't think of an easy way to accurately compute the column names, since they could include spaces.  The caller has to pass that in.

```
def getFldPositions( cliData, fldList ):
    pos = [ ]
    for curItem in fldList:
        pos.append( data.find(curItem))
    pos.append( pos[-1] + len(fldList[-1] ))
    return pos

def getCLIAsList( cliData, fldList ):
    pos = getPositions( cliData, fldList )
    newList = []
    for line in cliData.splitlines():
        newDict = [ ]
        for i, fld in enumerate(fldList):
            newDict.append( line[pos[i]:pos[i+1]].strip( ))
        newList.append(newDict)
    return newList

def getCLIAsDict( cliData ):
    pos = getPositions( cliData, fldList )
    newList = []
    for line in cliData.splitlines():
        newDict = { }
        for i, fld in enumerate(fldList):
            newDict.update([ ( fld, line[pos[i]:pos[i+1]].strip() ) ])
        newList.append(newDict)
    return newList

fldList = ['Client ID', 'Name', 'Value 1', 'Value 2']
data    = 'Client ID Name       Value 1 Value 2\n' \
          '5         Joe last   5 1     5 2\n' \
          '6         Frank Last 6 1     6 2\n'
theList = getCLIAsList( data, fldList )
# theList = getCLIAsDict( data, fldList )

print( theList )
print( 'ID: '  + theList[1][0] )
```

It returns this:

```
[['Client ID', 'Name', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'], ['5', 'Joe last', '5 1', '5 2'], ['6', 'Frank Last', '6 1', '6 2']]
ID: 6
```

Comment: Please note that this isn't perfect.  I tried to only provide 2 fields to make the call faster.  Using: ['Client ID', 'Name' ].  In this case the title is smaller than the data and I only got 4 characters from user names.  I have 2 work arounds adding a bunch of spaces a real hack OR adding a 3rd column.  I only care about the first 2 columns and the CLI is actually returning some 12 to 15 columns.  So a bit of a limitation for now.  If I can revisit this later I will.